How to Securely Authenticate SPAs in API Requests Using Client Identifiers?
I am developing a web API intended for consumption by users' Single-Page Applications (SPAs). Each SPA will be provided with identifiers like client_id, project_id, or publishable_key to make API requests. However, since these identifiers will be exposed in the client-side code, they are vulnerable to being stolen or misused by malicious applications.
TL;DR: How can I securely authenticate SPAs that are using non-secret client identifiers in their API requests? Is using client_id alone sufficient, or should additional measures be implemented?
Concerns

The client_id is visible in the frontend, making it non-confidential. What prevents a malicious application from using this client_id to access my API?
I am contemplating various solutions but am unsure about their effectiveness and security implications:

IP/Domains Whitelisting: Restrict API requests to whitelisted IPs or domains.
Backend Proxy: Require users to implement a backend that interacts with my authentication endpoint using client_id and client_secret to obtain an access_token, which the SPA then uses.
OAuth 2.0 PKCE: Although this method involves human interaction, which isn't applicable to my use case.



Additional Context
Many services integrating with web frontends (like Stripe, Firebase, Google APIs) use a single identifier like project_id or client_id. How do these platforms ensure the security of their APIs when accessed by SPAs?
I also have backend measures in place such as rate limiting, expiration settings for identifiers, and the ability for users to rotate their project_id.
Seeking Advice
Given these considerations, what are the best practices for securing APIs accessed by SPAs with visible client identifiers? Are there any standard methods or additional security layers I should consider implementing?
I've tried several methods to secure API access. Initially, I used only the client_id, expecting it to provide basic access control, but its visibility made it vulnerable. I then considered IP/domain whitelisting and a backend proxy method using client_id and client_secret for obtaining an access_token. While these methods increased security, they either lacked flexibility or added complexity for the users. Lastly, I looked into OAuth 2.0 with PKCE, but its user interaction requirement didn't suit all SPA workflows. I'm still searching for an optimal balance between security and user convenience.

What platform is the web API development?  For an MVC ASP.NET Core API, couldn't the SPA client send a username (or client_ID) and password in the body of a login request?  Are you providing the SPA client to users or are the users requrired to devlop their own?

@Cwinds for API dev we are using golang. Users are required to develop their own SPAs.
